# Grid/Layout using Bootstrap PHP and CSS

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I'm making cooking website and I automised displaying recipes with PHP and HTML.

I'm currently doing some front-end by using Bootstrap but I'm unable to do any decent grid where recipes will look neat and tidy. Also at some point bootstrap is not helping me with grind as I tried to pin up some griding bootstrap with it and css.
As it's automised I'm unable to sort it out and assign to particular column :(

Any help or suggestions will be very much appreciated!

I'm providing my code below
If someone would like to copy

```
    class RecipeLayout {
    private static $categories=null;
    public static function display($recipe){
        //part of code based on which user is being transfered to the other page with full details of the recipe
        echo '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">';
        echo "<img class='main_pg_recipe_img card-img-top'src='./public/images/". $recipe['recipe_image']."'/>";
        echo '<a href="./recipe_profile/recipe_mainpage.php?id='.$recipe['recipe_id'].' class="btn btn-primary">'.$recipe['recipe_title'] .'</a>';
        echo '<div class="recipe_home card-body">';
        echo '<h6 class="card-title"> Category: '.self::translateCategory($recipe['recipe_type']) .'</h6>';
        echo '<h6 class="card-title"> Calories: '.$recipe['recipe_calories'] .'</h6>';
        echo '<h6 class="card-title"> Serves: '.$recipe['recipe_serves'] .'</h6>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLvE4.png)
[desirable layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFoaa.png)

Comment: Could you please clarify "grinding" for me in this context?!

Comment: oh sure, sorry I will provide the picture how web is looking

Comment: @brombeer sorry for a lack of right explanation, if you are still interested I added picture what do I mean by grinding :) I meant to do layout, kinda invisible table which will hold it all together

Comment: No problem, just never heard "grinding" in context with frontend/bootstrap. And I think you mean "grid"? Like in [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)? You can use CSS Grid when using Bootstrap

Comment: Actually I will try if this will do

Comment: Also maybe post a screenshot of the layout how it is currently looking, so we can compare to the desirable layout you already posted. Feel free to get back here if you run into any trouble. Good luck ;)

Comment: @brombeer I added links :)